# Redirect all suburls to parent page

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect

On a wordpress website I have page with activities, that is available at `www.example.com/activities` url. I want to redirect all sub urls, like , `www.example.com/activities/all` or `www.example.com/activities/webinars` to the main url of the page `www.example.com/activities`. I've tried add below settings to  .htaccess, but it still gives 404 on any sub url, beside '/activities/'. Will really appreciate any thoughts. Thank you.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/activities/(.+)$  - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /page-activities.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect or mask the sub directory URL?  There's a distinct difference.

Comment: I want to redirect. The reason is because on parent url I have Vue.js app, and all suburl is the routes of that app. So I want to redirect all users who gets the direct access to the route to url, where app is based.